# How to get the name of the Key of a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to get the name of a KEY of a NSMutableDictionary in a for loop. But I am getting frustrated because I can't find the right function to get only the KEY without having to reference the object at all.

I would appreciate some guidance. the key I want is a String

```
NSMutableDictionary* myMutaDictionary = @{ @"theValeIwantOne":@{key:value},
                             @"theValeIwantTwo":@{key:value}
                           };

for (NSDictionary* myDictionary in myMutaDictionary) {
    NSString* key1 = //... code to get theValeIwantOne and theValeIwantTow;
}
```

I come from PHP where this operation is as simple as

```
foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {

    $thisIsMyKeyName = $key;
    $thisIsTheValueOfThatKey = $value;
}
```

Comment: That PHP code is not as simple as it looks...

Comment: its a classic foreach loop in php

Comment: Exactly.  The `foreach` loop in PHP has some major problems with state.  You can't nest `foreach` loops for the same array.

Comment: I'm intrigued to What problems you say the foreach loop has in PHP? I find it quite straight forward.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=21702

Comment: Yes, that's when the bug was submitted.  Note that it is marked as "Wont fix", which means that the bug has been around for over 10 years and there is no plan to ever fix it.

Comment: I do similar loops all the time with no issue. I will test it out tomorrow at work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for `keyEnumerator`

```
for (NSString *key in [dict keyEnumerator]) {
    NSString *value = [dict objectForKey:key];
}
```

Comment: @JonathanThurft: The type of the value here is `id`, not `NSString *`.

Comment: @JonathanThurft yes. I updated my answer. That said `id` by the way, not `int`. `id` just means some kind of object, like a string.